# show content on click on each item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list and i want to show content when i click on each item and hide the previous one. The only restriction is i have to use jquery 1.4.2

```
<ul class="list">
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
</ul>

<div>
<div class="content">1.1</div>
<div class="content">1.2</div>
<div class="content">1.3</div>
</div>

--script--
$('.content').hide();
$('#list li').live('click', function(){
    $('.content').eq($(this).index()).show();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the hiding siblings part and using the wrong selector type for your ul

```
$('.content').hide();
$('.list li').live('click', function(){
    $('.content').eq($(this).index()).show().siblings().hide(); // <-- here
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zcgYw

for jQuery 1.3.2 you have to change the way you're using index

```
$('.content').hide();
$('.list li').live('click', function(){
    var ind = $('li').index(this); // <-- this is how you have to use it
    $('.content').eq(ind).show().siblings().hide(); // <-- here
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vvrqK/

according to the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/index/), the other `.index()` and `.index('selector')` were not added until jQuery 1.4

Comment: sorry my bad...i said the version wrong...i just realized i gotta make it work for 1.3.2...i just cant imagine how i am going to build this for that version

Comment: @soum did you look at my second example? it should work for you

Comment: oh sorry..i missed that...worked great actually. RELIEF :-)
thanks again

Answer (score 1):

probably a typo on your part

`$('#list li')` should be `$('.list li')`

```
$('.list li').live('click', function(){
    $('.content').hide().eq($(this).index()).show();
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vjAmQ/2/